# nodejs express fs iterating files into array or object failing

Tags: node.js, express

So Im trying to use the nodejs express FS module to iterate a directory in my app, store each filename in an array, which I can pass to my express view and iterate through the list, but Im struggling to do so. When I do a console.log within the files.forEach function loop, its printing the filename just fine, but as soon as I try to do anything such as:

```
var myfiles = [];
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('./myfiles/', function (err, files) { if (err) throw err;
  files.forEach( function (file) {
    myfiles.push(file);
  });
});
console.log(myfiles);
```

it fails, just logs an empty object. So Im not sure exactly what is going on, I think it has to do with callback functions, but if someone could walk me through what Im doing wrong, and why its not working, (and how to make it work), it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The myfiles array is empty because the callback hasn't been called before you call console.log().

You'll need to do something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('./myfiles/',function(err,files){
    if(err) throw err;
    files.forEach(function(file){
        // do something with each file HERE!
    });
 });
 // because trying to do something with files here won't work because
 // the callback hasn't fired yet.
```

Remember, everything in node happens at the same time, in the sense that, unless you're doing your processing inside your callbacks, you cannot guarantee asynchronous functions have completed yet.

One way around this problem for you would be to use an EventEmitter:

```
var fs=require('fs'),
    EventEmitter=require('events').EventEmitter,
    filesEE=new EventEmitter(),
    myfiles=[];

// this event will be called when all files have been added to myfiles
filesEE.on('files_ready',function(){
  console.dir(myfiles);
});

// read all files from current directory
fs.readdir('.',function(err,files){
  if(err) throw err;
  files.forEach(function(file){
    myfiles.push(file);
  });
  filesEE.emit('files_ready'); // trigger files_ready event
});
```

Comment: +1 for digging deeper and explaining how you're supposed to use the callback.

Comment: Just use the Sync version of readdir instead if you need to wait for it to finish: [fs.readdirSync](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readdirSync)

Comment: @Cort3z: You're correct, but while that would have produced the correct result, it wouldn't have taught the OP why the problem occurred and how to resolve it when it happened again, in a different context.

Answer (score 6):

As several have mentioned, you are using an async method, so you have a nondeterministic execution path.

However, there is an easy way around this. Simply use the Sync version of the method:

```
var myfiles = [];
var fs = require('fs');

var arrayOfFiles = fs.readdirSync('./myfiles/');

//Yes, the following is not super-smart, but you might want to process the files. This is how:
arrayOfFiles.forEach( function (file) {
    myfiles.push(file);
});
console.log(myfiles);
```

That should work as you want. However, using sync statements is not good, so you should not do it unless it is vitally important for it to be sync.

Read more here: [fs.readdirSync](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readdirSync)

Comment: ↑ for the simplest answer.

Answer (score 5):

`fs.readdir` is asynchronous (as with many operations in node.js). This means that the `console.log` line is going to run before `readdir` has a chance to call the function passed to it.

You need to either:

Put the `console.log` line within the callback function given to `readdir`, i.e:

```
fs.readdir('./myfiles/', function (err, files) { if (err) throw err;
  files.forEach( function (file) {
    myfiles.push(file);
  });
  console.log(myfiles);
});
```

Or simply perform some action with each file inside the `forEach`.

Answer (score 3):

> I think it has to do with callback functions,

Exactly.

`fs.readdir` makes an asynchronous request to the file system for that information, and calls the callback at some later time with the results.

So `function (err, files) { ... }` doesn't run immediately, but `console.log(myfiles)` does.

At some later point in time, `myfiles` will contain the desired information.

You should note BTW that `files` is already an Array, so there is really no point in manually appending each element to some other blank array. If the idea is to put together the results from several calls, then use `.concat`; if you just want to get the data once, then you can just assign `myfiles = files` directly.

Overall, you really ought to read up on ["Continuation-passing style"](http://www.google.ca/search?q=continuation+passing+style).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and basing on answers given in this post I've solved it with **Promises**, that seem to be of perfect use in this situation:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var viewBag = {}; // It's just my little habit from .NET MVC ;)

  var readFiles = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir('./myfiles/',(err,files) => {
      if(err) { 
        reject(err); 
      } else {
        resolve(files);
      }
    });
  });

  // showcase just in case you will need to implement more async operations before route will response
  var anotherPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    doAsyncStuff((err, anotherResult) => {
      if(err) { 
        reject(err); 
      } else {
        resolve(anotherResult);
      }
    });
  });

  Promise.all([readFiles, anotherPromise]).then((values) => {
    viewBag.files = values[0];
    viewBag.otherStuff = values[1];
    console.log(viewBag.files); // logs e.g. [ 'file.txt' ]
    res.render('your_view', viewBag);
  }).catch((errors) => {
    res.render('your_view',{errors:errors}); // you can use 'errors' property to render errors in view or implement different error handling schema
  });
});
```

**Note:** you don't have to push found files into new array because you already get an array from fs.readdir()'c callback. According to node [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback):

> The callback gets two arguments (err, files) **where *files* is an array**
>   of the names of the files in the directory excluding '.' and '..'.

I belive this is very elegant and handy solution, and most of all - it doesn't require you to bring in and handle new modules to your script.